# How to find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}(\cos x-\sin x)^ndx$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to compute $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}(\cos x-\sin x)^n dx.$$

I tried the squeeze theorem, tried simplifying the integral, but I eventually got nothing.

Comment: And the differential?

Comment: @Clayton The bounds are definitely $0$ and $1$

Comment: HAve you tried Lebesgue Dominated Convergene Theorem?

Comment: it looks like it's bounded convergence

Comment: @TitoEliatron Unfortunately, I haven't learned that yet.

Comment: WHat is the background of your question?
What do you know? Uniform convergence of sequences? Only elemental calculus?

Comment: @TitoEliatron Only elemental calculus.

Comment: the graph grows bounded in the interval so it should be 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $(\cos(x)-\sin(x)) \leq 1-x$ over the range of integration, an upper bound for the integral is
$$\int_{0}^{1} (1-x)^n dx.$$
But,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} (1-x)^n dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n+1} = 0.$$

Because the original integral is positive for all $n$, the limit must be zero by the Squeeze theorem.

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: i guessed the correct method! I thought it would be bounded by (1-x)^n

Comment: I would assume  that the the statement "the original integral is positive" needs a proof.

Comment: Yes @user.  But this should be easy to show.

Comment: It may be harder than the rest of the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Observe $$\int_0^1f(x)^n\,dx=\int_0^\varepsilon f(x)^n\,dx+\int_\varepsilon^1 f(x)^n\,dx$$where $f(x)=\cos(x)-\sin(x)$. Now, for $0\leq x\leq 1$, we have $|\cos(x)-\sin(x)|\leq1$ with equality only when $x=0$. Then the first integral can be trivially estimated above by $\varepsilon$ and the second integral can be estimated above by $\cos(\varepsilon)^n(1-\varepsilon)<\cos^n(\varepsilon)$. Since $\cos(\varepsilon)<1$, this limit must go to $0$. In particular, for an arbitrary $\delta>0$, we can take $n$ large enough and $\varepsilon$ small enough so that $$\left|\int_0^1 f(x)^n\,dx\right|<\delta.$$This formally proves that the limit must equal $0$.