# How to find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n\int_{0}^{1}(\cos x-\sin x)^ndx$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, trigonometric-integrals

I want to compute

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n\int_{0}^{1}(\cos x-\sin x)^ndx$$

Someone helped me find [the limit of the integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3244447/how-to-find-lim-limits-n-to-infty-int-01-cos-x-sin-xndx), which is $0$, but now I can't figure out this one. Also tried squeeze theorem but I only get only one side of it to converge to $1$. Moreover, I'm bound to using elementary calculus.

Comment: Substitute $x=y/n$, compute the limit of the integrand and apply [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

Comment: @metamorphy Is DCT supposed to be elementary calculus? I don't know if it is, I was not taught it in elementary calculus (it was in a measure theory course)

Comment: @Rick I haven't learned DCT.

Comment: Yup !!! Exactly my point. Wait, until someone posts an answer or a hint. Also was the $n$ there or a $1/n$. Usually one sees a $1/n$.

Comment: @Rick Double checked. It's $n$. Otherwise it would've been simply $0$.

Comment: From the link in question, I guess the part you got the limit $1$ was from $\cos(x)- \sin(x) \le (1-x)$  Am I correct?

Comment: @Rick Yes, but I'm stuck only with the right side of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94267/discussion-between-rick-and-rares-st).

Comment: @metamorphy: What is the dominating function that you want to use?

Comment: @PhoemueX: As $\cos x-\sin x\leqslant 1-x$ is considered known, $e^{-y}$ would do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is another elementary way to get going. First, notice that:
$$\cos x - \sin x = \sqrt{2}\sin(\pi/4 - x).$$ 
Therefore, your integral, which we denote by $I_n$ is equal to:
$$I_n = n2^{\frac n2}\int_0^1\sin^n(\pi/4 - x)dx.$$
On the other hand, you can use integration by parts twice to show that:

$$\int\sin^nxdx = \frac{-\cos x \hspace{3pt} \sin^{n-1}x}{n} + \frac{(n-1)}{n} \int \sin^{n-2} x dx.$$

You can combine these two to obtain an explicit formula for $I_n.$

**Update:** This turned out to be interesting if we restrict ourselves to only elementary calculus. First, write:
$$I_n = n2^{n/2}\int_0^{\tfrac{\pi}{4}}\sin^n\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)dx+n2^{n/2}\int_{\tfrac{\pi}{4}}^1\sin^n\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)dx = $$
$$ = n2^{n/2}\int_0^{\tfrac{\pi}{4}}\sin^n\left(x\right)dx+n2^{n/2}\int_{\tfrac{\pi}{4}-1}^0\sin^n\left(x\right)dx = A_n+B_n.$$
Now, using $\sin x\leq x:$
$$|B_n|\leq n2^{n/2}\int_{\tfrac{\pi}{4}-1}^0|\sin^n\left(x\right)|dx=n2^{n/2}\int^{1-\tfrac{\pi}{4}}_0\sin^n\left(x\right)dx\leq$$
$$\dfrac{n}{n+1}\left(1-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)\left(\sqrt{2} - \dfrac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)^n\to 0.$$
Therefore, we simply need to study $A_n,$ which satisfies a rather simple recurrence relation (from integration by parts):
$$A_n = \dfrac{2n-2}{n-2}A_{n-2} - 1,\,\, A_1 = \sqrt{2}-1,\,\, A_2 = \dfrac{\pi}{2}-1.$$

Numerical evidence suggests that $A_n$ is positive, increasing and converging to $1$ as desired. Moreover, odd indices are of the form $\sqrt{2}a_n-b_n$ and the even indices are of the form $\pi c_n -d_n,$ where $a_n,b_n,c_n,d_n$ are all positive integers. In fact, one can easily find a closed form for $a_n:$
$$a_n = \dfrac{2^{3n}(n!)^2}{(2n)!},$$
while the closed form for $b_n$ seems to be very difficult, if possible at all.

However, based on what I have tried, finishing using only elementary approach from here seems rather difficult. A naive method is to use induction to prove the monotonicity. But that amounts to showing the following estimate:
$$A_n>\dfrac{n}{n+2}$$
or equivalently:
$$\int^{\tfrac{\pi}{4}}_0\sin^n\left(x\right)dx>\dfrac{1}{2^{n/2}(n+2)} (\dagger)$$ 
But above seems tricky as using the naive inequality $\sin(x)\geq\dfrac{2\sqrt{2}}{\pi}x$ on $[0,\pi/4]$ proves to be a too crude. I tried strenghtening it further by using:
$$\sin(x)\geq \dfrac{3}{\pi}x\cdot 1_{[0,\pi/6]}+\left(\dfrac{6(\sqrt{2}-1)}{\pi}x+\dfrac{3-2\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\cdot 1_{[\pi/6, \pi/4]}$$ 
which was again too strong.

Lastly, one can technically find a explicit formula by doing the following:
$$\dfrac{A_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)2^n\sqrt{2}} = -\int_0^{\tfrac{\pi}{4}}(\sin^2(x))^nd(\cos x) = \int_{\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^1(1-t^2)^ndt = $$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}\cdot\dfrac{1-2^{-k-\frac 12}}{2k+1}.$$
But again, this is not the nicest looking sum to manipulate.

**Update:** An elementary proof was found in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3254540/proving-int-0-pi-4-sinnx-dx-frac12n-2n2/3254570?noredirect=1#comment6692683_3254570) question and it was just a repeated application of integration by parts. Namely,
\begin{align}\int_0^{1/\sqrt{2}}\frac{t^n\,dt}{(1-t^2)^{1/2}}&=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(\left.\frac{t^{n+1}}{(1-t^2)^{1/2}}\right|_0^{1/\sqrt{2}}-\int_0^{1/\sqrt{2}}\frac{t^{n+2}\,dt}{(1-t^2)^{3/2}}\right)\\&=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(2^{-n/2}-\frac{1}{n+3}\left.\frac{t^{n+3}}{(1-t^2)^{3/2}}\right|_0^{1/\sqrt{2}}+\ldots\right)\\&>\frac{2^{-n/2}}{n+1}\left(1-\frac{1}{n+3}\right)=2^{-n/2}\frac{n+2}{(n+2)^2-1}>\dfrac{2^{n/2}}{n+2}.\end{align}
Thus, the proof is complete and should completely fall in the elementary calculus scope.

Comment: This seems a lot more straightforward than what I did, great find!

Comment: It is difficult to obtain an explicit formula for $I_n$.  Wolfram|Alpha can give the formula, but it is very complicated using Gamma function and Hyper-geometric function!

Comment: And how should I use the last integral to solve the main one?

Comment: @rares_st plug in the bounds to obtain a recurrence relation. Solving that explicitly results in something ugly, but there might be a clever way pass onto the limit.

Comment: @dezdichado Seems impossible with basic, elementary calculus

Comment: @dezdichado I used this to get a recurrence of the form $2\frac{n-1}{n-2}I_{n-2}-I_n=1-a\cdot c^n$, where $a$ is some negative constant and $-1<c<0$. Taking the limit on both sides says $\lim I_n = 1$ - however, only if we already know that $I_n$ converges, which I couldn't figure out how to do without rehashing much of my own answer. Do you have any idea how convergence might be easily established?

Comment: @J_P, if differentiating under the integral sign is considered elementary, then I think $I'(\alpha)=\dfrac{I(\alpha)}{\alpha}+\alpha^2\dfrac{I(\alpha-1)}{\alpha-1}$ and the fact that $I(\alpha)$ is positive, bounded for $\alpha\geq 1$ implies that it is convergent. I will try think of something even more basic though.

Comment: I'm concerned about introducing a continuous parameter $\alpha$ in place of $n$ as $\cos(x)-\sin(x)$ is negative near $1$ and so raising it to $\alpha$ makes the whole thing complex so you have to be careful about what you mean by "positive" etc.

Comment: Also, I'm not quite sure how you got that expression for $I'(\alpha)$, differentiating under the integral sign gives $\int_0^1 (\cos(x)-\sin(x))^\alpha\log(\cos(x)-\sin(x))\mathrm{d}x$. How do you calculate this? We know that $I(\infty)=1$, which means your expression for $I'$ diverges for large $\alpha$, which is unusual.

Comment: @J_P you are right, I took the derivative wrong.

Comment: @J_P,  added some details. Based on what I have tried, I'd say that a truly elementary solution to this problem is either impossible or requires some immense cleverness.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how much calculus you know, if anything is foreign let me know and I'll try to leave an addendum in an edit. Also, I've been editing this answer over and over because I keep finding mistakes so hopefully it's converged to something sensible by now, but I can't be sure.

Let $f(x)=\cos(x)-\sin(x)$. First, some facts about $f$ on $[0,1]$:

- $f(x)\leq1-x$, as you know from your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3244447/how-to-find-lim-limits-n-to-infty-int-01-cos-x-sin-xndx?noredirect=1&lq=1),
- $f(x)\geq1-\frac{3}{2}x$, as $f(x) = \sqrt{2}\sin(\pi/4 - x)$ and so its derivative is never less than $-\sqrt{2}>-3/2$.

These together imply that for any $\delta\in(0,1)$ there exists an $0< M < 1$ so that $\vert f(x)\vert<M$ on the interval $[\delta,1]$.

The idea behind the following is that for large $n$ most of the integral comes from a small neighbourhood of $0$, so we only keep a small slice around it.

Notice that $f''(0)<0$, so the function is concave on some interval $I=[0,x_0]$, i.e. for any $\delta\in I:$
$$
\forall t\in[0,\delta]:f(t)>1-\frac{t}{\delta}(1-f(\delta))
$$
This is because the RHS is a linear function connecting the points $(0,f(0))$ and $(\delta,f(\delta))$ and its derivative is smaller than $f'(0)$. Now split your integral as:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1(\cos(u)-\sin(u))^n\mathrm{d}u=\int_0^\delta(\cos(u)-\sin(u))^n\mathrm{d}u+\int_\delta^1&(\cos(u)-\sin(u))^n\mathrm{d}u=\\
&=S_1(\delta;n) + S_2(\delta;n)
\end{align*}
Notice that as $\vert f(x)\vert<M$ on $[\delta,1]$, so we can estimate:
$$
\vert S_2(\delta;n)\vert<\left\vert\int_\delta^1(\cos(u)-\sin(u))^n\mathrm{d}u\right\vert<\int_\delta^1M^n\mathrm{d}u<M^n
$$
On the other hand, we can also estimate $S_1$:
$$
S_1(\delta;n)>\int_0^\delta\left(1-\frac{u}{\delta}(1-f(\delta)) \right)^n\mathrm{d}u=\delta\frac{1-f(\delta)^{n+1}}{1-f(\delta)}\frac{1}{n+1}
$$
Observe that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\delta\frac{1-f(\delta)^{n+1}}{1-f(\delta)}\frac{n}{n+1}&=\frac{\delta}{1-f(\delta)}\\
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}nM^n &=0
\end{align*}
The limits follow because $\vert f(\delta)\vert < 1$ and $\vert M\vert < 1$ and so those terms fall exponentially fast. Therefore:
\begin{align*}
nS_1(\delta;n)&>\frac{\delta}{1-f(\delta)}+\epsilon_1(n;\delta)\\
nS_2(\delta;n)&=0+\epsilon_2(n;\delta)
\end{align*}
Here $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ vanish in the limit of large $n$ for each $\delta$.
We finally have that for all $\delta\in(0,x_0]$:
$$
n\int_0^1(\cos(u)-\sin(u))^n\mathrm{d}u=nS_1(\delta;n)+nS_2(\delta;n)>\frac{\delta}{1-f(\delta)}+\epsilon_1(n;\delta)+\epsilon_2(n;\delta)
$$
We can quickly evaluate by L'Hospital's rule that 
$$
\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\frac{\delta}{1-f(\delta)}=\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{0-(-\sin(\delta)-\cos(\delta))}=1
$$
So for all $n,\delta$ (the left $\geq$ follows from estimates with $1-x$ that you've done yourself):
$$
1\geq n\int_0^1(\cos(u)-\sin(u))^n\mathrm{d}u\geq 1+\epsilon_3(\delta)+\epsilon_1(n;\delta)+\epsilon_2(n;\delta)
$$
$\epsilon_3$ has analogous meaning to the other two.

Since we're dealing with functions of $n, \delta$ here, we have to be careful with taking the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$. In fact, just to be sure, let's do it by definition. Pick some $\eta>0$. Then, pick a $\delta'$ so small that $\vert\epsilon_3(\delta')\vert < \eta/3$. At this $\delta'$, we can pick an $N$ so large that $\vert\epsilon_1(n;\delta')\vert<\eta/3$ and $\vert\epsilon_2(n;\delta')\vert<\eta/3$ for all $n>N$. Due to the above inequalities, we now have
$$
\forall n>N:1+\eta>1\geq n\int_0^1(\cos(u)-\sin(u))^n\mathrm{d}u>1-\eta/3-\eta/3-\eta/3=1-\eta
$$
Thus we've directly established
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\int_0^1(\cos(u)-\sin(u))^n\mathrm{d}u=1
$$

Comment: Imagine having this at an exam. Hopefully few people know about this limit

Comment: @rares_st Perhaps this was intended to be done using DCT, as one commenter suggested. That way certainly isn't easy (at least to me), but it is certainly less finicky than this. Maybe it's possible to avoid DCT altogether using some clever arguments, but I wouldn't know.

Comment: Also, see my comment under dezdichado's answer, if we could establish just the fact that $I_n$ converges (which seems obvious but is actually not so straightforward), I think we could get the answer more quickly using his method.

Comment: The funny part is that I found this one in a book with exercises for my univ exam

Comment: As in, an exam to get into uni? Well, perhaps there is some simple way that we just haven't found, who can say.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative solution**

For $n\ge 4$, we have
\begin{align*}
I_n &= n\int_0^{1/\sqrt{n}} (\cos x - \sin x)^n \mathrm{d} x
+ n\int_{1/\sqrt{n}}^{\pi/4} (\cos x - \sin x)^n \mathrm{d} x\\
&\quad + n\int_{\pi/4}^1 (\cos x - \sin x)^n \mathrm{d} x\\
&= I_{n, 1} + I_{n, 2} + I_{n, 3}.
\end{align*}

Let us prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} I_{n, 1} = 1$, $\lim_{n\to \infty} I_{n, 2} = 0$,
and $\lim_{n\to \infty} I_{n, 3} = 0$.

1. First, since $|\cos x - \sin x| = \sin x - \cos x \le \sin x \le \sin 1$ for all $x$ in $[\pi/4, 1]$, we have
   $$|I_{n, 3}| \le n\int_{\pi/4}^1 |\cos x - \sin x|^n \mathrm{d} x
   \le n (\sin 1)^n (1 - \pi/4).$$
   Since $\lim_{n\to \infty} n (\sin 1)^n (1 - \pi/4) = 0$, by the squeeze theorem, we have
   $$\lim_{n\to \infty} I_{n, 3} = 0.$$
2. Second, it is easy to prove that $0\le \cos x - \sin x
   \le \cos \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - \sin \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \le 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ for
   all $n\ge 4$ and all $x$ in $[1/\sqrt{n}, \pi/4]$. Thus, we have
   $$0 \le I_{n, 2} \le n\left(1 - \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n\frac{\pi}{4}.$$
   Since $\lim_{n\to \infty} n\left(1 - \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n = 0$, by the squeeze theorem, we have
   $$\lim_{n\to \infty} I_{n, 2} = 0.$$
3. Third, with the substitution $x = \frac{y}{\sqrt{n}}$, using $(\cos x - \sin x)^2 = 1 - \sin 2x$, we have
   $$I_{n, 1}
   = \int_0^1 \sqrt{n}\left(1 - \sin \frac{2y}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{n/2} \mathrm{d} y.$$
   It is easy to prove that, for all $y$ in $[0, 1]$ and all $n\ge 4$,
   $$\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\frac{2y}{\sqrt{n}} \le \sin \frac{2y}{\sqrt{n}} \le \frac{2y}{\sqrt{n}}.$$
   Thus, we have
   $$\int_0^1 \sqrt{n}\left(1 - \frac{2y}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{n/2} \mathrm{d} y \le I_{n, 1} \le \int_0^1 \sqrt{n}\left(1 -  \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\frac{2y}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{n/2} \mathrm{d} y$$
   which results in
   $$\frac{n \left(1 - \left(1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{n/2 + 1}\right)}{n+2}
   \le I_{n, 1} \le \frac{n^2 \left(1 - \left(1 - \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{n/2 + 1}\right)}{(n+2)(n-1)}.$$
   Since
   \begin{align*}
   \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n \left(1 - \left(1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{n/2 + 1}\right)}{n+2} &= 1, \\
   \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n^2 \left(1 - \left(1 - \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{n/2 + 1}\right)}{(n+2)(n-1)} &= 1,
   \end{align*}
   by the squeeze theorem, we have $\lim_{n\to \infty} I_{n, 1} = 1$.

Thus, we have $\lim_{n\to \infty} I_n = 1$.

We are done.